# How to solve singulartiy in NIntegration?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have an integral

```
 NIntegrate[1/(x - x*Log[x]), {x, 0, E}, Method -> "PrincipalValue", 
  Exclusions -> {0, E}, PrecisionGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 13];
```

and I can't solve it. 
Can anyone take a look and show me how to do it?

Comment: I get $58.605...$.  Do you have any reason to doubt that answer?

Comment: @David G. Stork: Yes, I do. The answer in version 11.3 is supplied with NIntegrate obtained \
61.6898965566571980569209393874979487231066384596339583582607001 and \
1.87176935662578407544374941801080191407846253122765831122636127 for \
the integral and error estimates

Comment: @user64494 MMA 11.2 returns an answer $61.68...$, together with warnings about slow convergence. Can you explain exactly what your problem is though?

Comment: @MarcoB: Could you kindly look at my comment to the Sungmin's answer?

Comment: If I try to solve the problem with this code i get an error message saying it didn't converge and that numeric integration is converging slowly. I don't get any kind of result

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not really a Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having grasped the mathematics involved.

Answer (score 3):

Your integral can be done symbolically:

```
Integrate[1/(x-x Log[x]), {x, 0, E}, PrincipalValue->True]
```

> ∞

Comment: Integrate[1/(x - x Log[x]), {x, 0, E}] says Integrate::idiv: Integral of 1/(x-x Log[x]) does not converge on {0,E}.

Answer (score 2):

This is more or less a comment. It seems that the integral diverges.

```
f[x_] = Integrate[ 1/(x - x*Log[x]), x]
r = Assuming[ {\[Epsilon] > 0},
    Series[ f[E - \[Epsilon]] - f[\[Epsilon]], {\[Epsilon], 0, 1}]
]
r // Normal // ReplaceAll[\[Epsilon] -> 0]
(* \[Infinity] *)
```

Comment: Yes, the singularity at $x=0$ causes the divergence in view of Series[1/(x - x*Log[x]), {x, 0, 2}] which outputs $$\frac{1}{x (1-\log (x))}+O\left(x^4\right). $$

Comment: Can you tell me why some integrals, for instance NIntegral of x^-0.5 from 0 to 1 is converging. Although there is singularity in 0?